# Why doesn't the connection string set in Azure Application Settings replace the one in the appsettings file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I try to host my ASP.Net Core Website and also the database (PostGresql) on Azure.

The problem is, that the connectionstring set in the Application Settings on Azure does not replace the connectionstring given by the appsettings file. So it gives me an error, that "data source" is no valid parameter for the connectionstring (which is right, but I use it localy)

I tried to give azure the appsettings.json with an empty and with no defined connectionstring but it still wont change the connectionstring. I checked the error message and it seems to be pretty obvious:

[Errormessage from Logstream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmEz8.png)

The error shows, that there is a problem with the parameter "data source" witch makes sense (thats the way I use it localy for developement) but as far as the Application Settings would replace the connectionstring there would be no "data source" parameter.

I also checked the web.config file in kudu witch is the following:

[web.config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUc89.png)

I have no idea why it does not replace the connection string.

Here is my program.cs

```
// Retrieve the connection string
string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext");

// Load configuration from Azure App Configuration
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(connectionString);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")));
```

And this is my appsettings.json

```
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ApplicationDbContext": "Data Source=SpringOutreach.db"
```

And this is the connectionstring I set in azure:

Server=anyserver-server.postgres.database.azure.com;Database=any-database;Port=5432;Ssl Mode=Require;User Id=anyuser;Password=anypassword;

Comment: The most obvious is if you've forgotten to tell your application to *use* azure application settings but since you're not showing us any code it's difficult to tell if that's so

Comment: Thanks, I quickly added my code (are these the parts you need). @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Could it be possible, that the mistake is actually more on the side of the connectionstring format? I've now also received the error - Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Invalid connection string format.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create your server-side firewall rules.
Firewall rules are needed to connect on-premises and other Azure resources to databases.

In addition...you would also need to add your client dev-box to the firewall rules if you going to be accessing that database while developing.

Its a fairly straightforward process:[Quickstart: Create a server-level firewall rule in Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart?view=azuresql)

Comment: As far as I see, this would apply on a Azure SQL Database. I use a PostGreSQL Database.

Comment: @Micha Firewall setting are OS and database independent. The procedures are different...just keep this in mind while your digging for the answer.

Comment: I understand. I adapted the firewall rules, but it still does not work. I now also tried to hardcode the Connectionstring into my appsettings.json and then it seems to work. It is the same string. Any idea? @Chris Catignani